# using child text of an element to set/update a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, use-state

Does anyone know what I could to my `<li>` elements in the following component so that clicking on one of the `<li>` elements would set activityType to the text contained in that particular `<li>`? For example, the first `<li>` is "Education." Clicking on that one, I would want this to happen: setActivityType('education').

Does anyone know what I could do to my `<li>` elements in the following component so that clicking on one of the `<li>`s would set `activityType` to the text contained in the particular `<li>`? For example, the first `<li>` is 'Education.' Click on that one, I would want this to happen: `setActivityType('education')`

**TypeMenu.js:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const TypeMenu = () => {
    const [activityType, setActivityType] = useState('');

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Please select an activity type:</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>Education</li>
                <li>Recreational</li>
                <li>Social</li>
                <li>DIY</li>
                <li>Charity</li>
                <li>Cooking</li>
                <li>Relaxation</li>
                <li>Music</li>
                <li>Busywork</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TypeMenu;
```

**UPDATE:**

I took the advice given and put the child text for each `<li>` element in an array. I then mapped over that array, to create the individual `<li>`'s, giving each one an onClick that ideally, would set `activityType` to the text from `<li>` that I click on. I then want to make an API call based off of whatever `activityType` is dynamically set to. With the code below, I got a step closer to solving this problem but I am still unable to control/update `activityType` with the code as is. That const is coming back as an empty string, which is throwing my API call off. Any suggestions?

**TypeMenu.js:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { getActivityByType } from "../actions";

const TypeMenu = props => {
    const [activityType, setActivityType] = useState('');

    const activityArr = [
        'Education',
        'Recreational',
        'Social',
        'DIY',
        'Charity',
        'Cooking',
        'Relaxation',
        'Music',
        'Busywork'
    ];

    const returnActivity = (t) => {
        setActivityType(t.toLowerCase());
        props.getActivityByType(activityType);
    }

    console.log(activityType);

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Please select an activity type:</h2>
            <ul>
                {activityArr.map(type => (
                    <li key={type} onClick={() => returnActivity(type)}>{type}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default connect(null, { getActivityByType })(TypeMenu);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give each list item an onClick function that sets the activity type. I would also store your activity types in an array and map each one to a list item, rather than writing them out individually.

Something like this:

```
const activityTypes = [
  'Education',
  'Recreational',
  ... // etc
]

const TypeMenu = () => {
  const [activityType, setActivityType] = useState('');

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Please select an activity type:</h2>
      <ul>
        {activityTypes.map(t => (
          <li onClick={() => setActivityType(t)}>{t}</li>
         ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Update:

Change `props.getActivityByType(activityType)` to `props.getActivityByType(t)`. State doesn't change until the next render, so the value of `activityType` is still the previous value.

Comment: I followed your advice and am almost there. Can you check go back to my question which I've now edited with updated code and see if you can figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Your issue is that you are referring to the state value, but the state value hasn't been updated yet because the component has not re-rendered.